# Getting an "Error: Could not find or load main class" while running EMR?

Tags: java, hadoop, alibaba-cloud

I am trying to run jobs in Alibaba Cloud E-MapReduce, it throws me an error like

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

For even while trying to execute predefined examples like word count this error occurs, so that I think I am having some configuration error.

What I am missing?

Comment: You're missing Java dependencies for your code. Would help if you provided the class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alibaba Cloud E-MapReduce requires the path protocol header of the Job Jar as **ossref** in the job configuration.

just check the job configuration, if it is not ossref, change it to ossref.

I hope this will solve your problem.